# TailRec optimisation and export

Tags: scala, export, tail-recursion, scala-3

What's wrong with the following code?

```
class A {
  val m = new scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap[Int, Int]()
  export m.clear
}
```

The compilation error (Scala 3.4.0):
"TailRec optimisation not applicable, method clear contains no recursive calls".

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Scala to me. Worth opening an issue on their GitHub.

Comment: Issue #19505 (#20011) which is fixed on 3.4.1.

Comment: Links for anyone interested: https://github.com/scala/scala3/issues/19505, https://github.com/scala/scala3/issues/20011